# Silverlight Async

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight

What is the reason behind async call for SilverLight? You can't have a sync call when communicating with a WCF service?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might want to read [OMG, Silverlight! Asynchronous is Evil! (or, Call me back when you got it)](http://petesbloggerama.blogspot.com/2008/07/omg-silverlight-asynchronous-is-evil.html)

> The bottom line is this: if Microsoft were to allow every petition-signing Tom, Dick and Harry blowhard / hotshot developer to make synchronous calls because they are too lazy and crybaby to learn how to do it better, there would DEFINITELY be a lot of very unhappy people with frozen browsers out there in SilverLand -- and guess who would get blamed? Microsoft!

Answer (score 4):

Because your UI hangs while waiting for syncronous webservice calls to complete.  Depending on the user's network and connectivity state, that could be a very long wait - and a very poor user experience if your UI is hung for that long

Comment: ...and then everyone would blame Microsoft if you opted for Sync behavior and hung the browser.

Comment: But isnt the same issue with lets say asp.net ? or its because asp.net is server side and silverlight is client side ?

Comment: Yes, its generally a bad idea to make synchronous webservice calls.